failed to get recent blockhash: SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get recent blockhash: Method not found
todo.js:132 adding todo: Error: failed to get recent blockhash: SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get recent blockhash: Method not found
    at Connection.getRecentBlockhash (index.browser.esm.js:6542:13)
    at async ot.sendAndConfirm (index.js:57:8041)
    at async addTodo (todo.js:122:31)
console.error

the above is the error I am facing, below is the addTodo block
const addTodo = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (program && publicKey) {
            try {
                setTransactionPending(true);

                // Fetch the latest blockhash
                const latestBlockhashInfo = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
                const { blockhash } = latestBlockhashInfo;

                const [profilePda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
                    [Buffer.from('USER_STATE'), publicKey.toBuffer()],
                    program.programId
                );

                const content = input.trim();
                if (!content) {
                    setTransactionPending(false);
                    return;
                }

                const [todoPda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
                    [Buffer.from('TODO_STATE'), publicKey.toBuffer(), Uint8Array.from([lastTodo])],
                    program.programId
                );

                const tx = new anchor.web3.Transaction().add(
                    await program.methods.addTodo(content).accounts({
                        todoAccount: todoPda,
                        userProfile: profilePda,
                        authority: publicKey,
                        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                    }).instruction()
                );

                tx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
                tx.feePayer = publicKey;

                const txSig = await program.provider.sendAndConfirm(tx);
                console.log('Transaction successful with signature:', txSig);

                setLastTodo((prev) => prev + 1);
                setTodos((prevTodos) => [
                    ...prevTodos,
                    { account: { content, marked: false, idx: lastTodo } }
                ]);
                setInput("");
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error adding todo:', error);
            } finally {
                setTransactionPending(false);
            }
        }
    };
    ```


It looks like you might be using a library that still uses getRecentBlockhash which was removed in the agave 2.0 transition
You might have to update your libraries to their latest versions or find the one that is causing this error
Here is the link to the transition guide and a the list of RPC methods affected: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/wiki/Agave-v2.0-Transition-Guide#step-2-review-removed-rpc-endpoints-and-sdk-elements
